# Uploading files to Express Server Inconsistency TypeError NetworkError only on videos

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, busboy

I've been trying to get a simple upload/download web application working for images and videos.

I have a simple form in my `index.html` file.

```
<form>
    <input id="upload", type="file", multiple="multiple" />
</form>
```

And a just-as-simple upload function in my `index.js`.

```
document.getElementById("upload").onchange = function() {
    let photo = document.getElementById("upload").files[0];
    let formData = new FormData();
             
    formData.append("photo", photo);
    fetch("/upload", {method: "POST", body: formData});
}
```

My Express server looks like this:

```
var app = express(); // var express = require("express");
app.use(busboy());   // var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
app.use(cors());     // var cors = require('cors');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.route('/upload')
    .post(function (req, res, next) {
        var fstream;
        req.pipe(req.busboy);
        req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
            if (fs.existsSync(__dirname + '/public/uploaded/' + filename.filename)) {
                res.sendStatus(409);
            } else {
                console.log("Uploading: " + filename.filename);

                //Path where image will be uploaded
                fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/public/uploaded/' + filename.filename, {flags: "w+"});
                file.pipe(fstream);
                fstream.on('close', function () {    
                    console.log("Upload Finished of " + filename.filename);              
                    res.redirect('back');
                });
            }
            
        });
    });

var server = app.listen(4200, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

Heirarchy is this:

```
project folder
- server.js
- public
--- index.html
--- index.js
--- uploaded (destination for file upload)
----- conflicting.mov
```

I run `npm server.js` and go to `http://127.0.0.1:4200` and this works! Mostly. For images. Not videos. Basically, if the file to be uploaded is already being hosted by the server, then I want the server to reject the POST request with a 409 status.

But, if the file does not exist on the server, then yep, the server should upload the file successfully.

I can upload files fine if it doesn't conflict with an already existing file. But when I attempt to reupload a .mov (or .mp4) file, then it never uploads and I get a `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.` It works fine for conflicting images and the 409 error is sent correctly, but not videos.

I've tried all sorts of answers from this site, including Formidable, BodyParser, etc. to parse the request, to no avail. I have no idea why .jpg and other common file extentions work, but video files do not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I am willing to answer more questions if the information I provided was not detailed enough.

Comment: Why open the file with `w+`?  It's better not to check with exists (it's a race condition anyway because as soon as you observe that it doesn't exist, some other process in the system might create the file).  Just create the write stream optimistically with flags `wx` which will throw an exception if the file existed at the time of creation.  And *handle the exception*.

Comment: @Wyck Just tried it, getting the same `Uncaught TypeError` as in my question above. Here's a pastebin of my attempt of your suggestion: https://pastebin.com/bUmxKG3r